# IntelliJ move caret to next paragraph

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a shortcut similiar to `{` and `}` in vim? I.e. move to block start/end?

Use case: Caret is at the beginning of tons of imports, want to move caret to next blank line after imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the different kepmaps for the caret movement in the IntelliJ IDE by going to `File->Settings->Keymap`, where in the seach bar you type `Move Caret`.

[image]

In your case you can use `Ctrl+Up` to move the Caret Backwards and `Ctrl+Down` to move it forwards. There are many other bindings that you can use and see in that menu. You can even re-map them all you want!

Answer (score 0):

In a code block, you can use "Code block start" and "Code block end" actions (Cmd-Alt-[, Cmd-Alt-] in the default Mac keymap, Ctrl-[ and Ctrl-] in the default keymap on other operating systems).

This shortcut doesn't work in the import block, but normally this is not needed because the standard way to work with imports in IntelliJ is to use "Auto import" and "Optimize imports" actions, and you simply never put the caret in the import list.